# Getting the length of a String value in StringTemplate

Tags: string, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

[According to the documentation](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Expressions#Expressions-Propertyreferences) you can reference properties of objects in the `<object.property>` format. I was hoping this would let me check the length of a String, but it doesn't seem to work. I think this is because the method is `String.length()`, and according to the documentation if I do something like `<mystr.length>` it will look for a method called `getLength()` and a field named `length`, but it never looks for a method called `length()`. I verified with this quick check in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> import org.stringtemplate.v4._; import scala.collection.JavaConverters._;
import org.stringtemplate.v4._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> new ST("<xs:{ x | <x>:<x.length> }>").add("xs", List("hello", "goodbye").asJava).render
res0: String = "hello: goodbye: "

scala> case class S(val s:String) { def getLength = s.length }
defined class S

scala> new ST("<xs:{ x | <x>:<x.length> }>").add("xs", List("hello", "goodbye").map(S).asJava).render
res1: String = "S(hello):5 S(goodbye):7 "
```

So if Strings had a `getLength()` method or a `length` field it would work...

Is there an easier way to get the String length? Maybe a built-in StringTemplate function, or some other method that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Cheatsheet's list of Functions](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet#StringTemplatecheatsheet-Functions): `strlen`

```
scala> new ST("<xs:{ x | <x>:<strlen(x)> }>").add("xs", List("hello", "goodbye").asJava).render
res6: String = "hello:5 goodbye:7 "
```